# assigned a dropdown selection as a variable and returning it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to make it so that the option that a user selects is put in a textarea after a button is clicked. Sadly it does not work as intended at this point.

My html that matters:

```
<select id="bammon1">
            <option>Please select a pokemon</option>
                <option>1) Simorgh</option>
                <option>2) --</option>
                <option>3) Flytrap</option>
                <option>4) Name Needed</option>
                <option>5) Pandoze </option>
                <option>6) Apaflite </option>
                <option>7) Dendurus</option>
                <option>8) Bandirto</option>
                <option>9) --</option>
                <option>10) Tiflectum</option>
                <option>11) Sinder</option>
                <option>12) --</option>
                <option>13) Springfest</option>
                <option>14) Mirrage</option>
                <option>15) Skulprit</option>
                <option>16) --</option>
                <option>17) --</option>
                <option>18) Swelter</option>
                <option>19) Tundear </option>
                <option>20) Slimurk </option>
                <option>21) Sluborac</option>
                <option>22) Ogre </option>
                <option>23) Name Needed</option>
                <option>24) Name Needed</option>
                <option>25) Cychill </option>
                <option>26) Cydnidie</option>
                <option>27) Name Needed</option>
                <option>28) Name Needed</option>
                <option>29) Name Needed </option>
                <option>30) Farenheat</option>
</select>
<textarea value=""id=team cols="50" rows="10"> </textarea>

    <button type="button" id=teambtn class="btn">Export</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#teambtn').click(function() {
var P1 = document.getElementById("bammon1");
var Pokemon1 = P1.options[P1.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById('team').value= Pokemon1;
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason to mix jQuery with javascript?

Comment: oh, is the fact that I'm mixing them the problem? I;m fine with just making it either/or

Comment: I don't think the problem is there. I just ask :-) Did you wrap your code above with `$( document ).ready(function() {` ?

Comment: No I didn't I should wrap the JS code with that then?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Also make sure you include jQuery script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use jQuery itself like below it works.

Hope it helps!

```js
$('#teambtn').click(function() {
var $myTextArea = $('textarea#team');
var Pokemon1 = $("#bammon1 option:selected").val();
$myTextArea.text($myTextArea.text()+' '+Pokemon1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="bammon1">
            <option>Please select a pokemon</option>
                <option>1) Simorgh</option>
                <option>2) --</option>
                <option>3) Flytrap</option>
                <option>4) Name Needed</option>
                <option>5) Pandoze </option>
                <option>6) Apaflite </option>
                <option>7) Dendurus</option>
                <option>8) Bandirto</option>
                <option>9) --</option>
                <option>10) Tiflectum</option>
                <option>11) Sinder</option>
                <option>12) --</option>
                <option>13) Springfest</option>
                <option>14) Mirrage</option>
                <option>15) Skulprit</option>
                <option>16) --</option>
                <option>17) --</option>
                <option>18) Swelter</option>
                <option>19) Tundear </option>
                <option>20) Slimurk </option>
                <option>21) Sluborac</option>
                <option>22) Ogre </option>
                <option>23) Name Needed</option>
                <option>24) Name Needed</option>
                <option>25) Cychill </option>
                <option>26) Cydnidie</option>
                <option>27) Name Needed</option>
                <option>28) Name Needed</option>
                <option>29) Name Needed </option>
                <option>30) Farenheat</option>
</select>
<textarea value=""id=team cols="50" rows="10"> </textarea>

    <button type="button" id=teambtn class="btn">Export</button>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use this. See my comment on my answer.

Comment: Right now the question doesn't has value and this works. If the situation does have value, the correct value will be returned. I could have used `$("#bammon1 option:selected").text();` but I didn't for that sole purpose. Any day the user chooses to add specific values to items, the `.val()` based code will still work so I'd go with that for the case.

Comment: amitthk I have another question to add on, how can I make it so that if I click the button again that it inserts the text again?

Comment: Hi Dominik Yakoubek, I Updated the code above. I am just adding on to the earlier text the new selection. I hope this is how you need it? Thanks

Comment: Eh, not really, that adds it to the textarea with a bunch of blank space before it. To clarify what I meant I wanted to be able to paste it again after I manually change the text in the text box(say I cut and paste it). Either way thanks, you were still a big help.

Comment: Hey man, sorry for asking another question, what would I do if I gave the options values and wanted to have the values in the text box?

Comment: Same should work.  Please try. If you want the text rather, then use `var Pokemon1 = $("#bammon1 option:selected").text();` instead. Lemme know if there's any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `option` elements don't have a `value`. Options have a text and a value, like this:

```
<option value="value">text</option>
```

You can use javascript's `.innerText` or jQuery's `.text()` to access the text, or you can give them a `value` that is the same as the text. If you're posting this information to a server, it's the `value` that gets posted.

Comment: jQuery returns the text instead of the value on a `.val()` call if there isn't a value attribute on the element. This is however terrible practice because if someone comes in later and adds `value` attributes to the options, that code will suddenly start returning the real value and break everything.

Comment: Since the `value` attribute isn't there, thre's no problem. The script does not reffer to the `option` but `select` element. Every browser will return what is between open-close option tags. It's the same as with `input`.

Comment: Referring to the `select` instead of the `option` doesn't make any difference; `[select element].val()` will still return the `value` of the selected `option` if a value attribute exists. (See http://jsfiddle.net/kr90tw04/). This creates a time bomb if they're ever added. If you want the option text, ask for `.text()` which always returns that instead of `.val()` which sometimes happens to.